# How can i ogstash input jdbc error handling

Tags: logstash

This is my

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/postgresql.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://*.*.*.*/database"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "postgres"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM table limit 1"
    connection_retry_attempts => 5
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 10
  }
}

output {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "*"
    topic_id => "topic001"
    codec => json_lines {}
  }
}
```

Can i statement write on file when log warn or error??

Or can i retry statement when warn or error log??

I tried this for error handling

```
filter {
  if [@timestamp] {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "destination" => "output1" }
    }
  } else {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "destination" => "output2" }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as i know, @timestamp must insert on kafka message. So i used them for if condition. But when input failure not work filter